# The function returns the DFS traversal of the graph represented by the adjacency matrix.javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 Blockquote
 >inside it write a JavaScript function that takes 3 arguments: an adjacency matrix in the form of 
 >a 2D array, number of nodes, and starting vertex.
>The function returns the DFS traversal of the graph represented by the adjacency matrix.
```

> For example,
>       for adjacency matrix: `[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]` , number of nodes: 4 
>        and starting vertex: 3,
>        the output must be `[ 3, 2, 0, 1 ]`.
>      ''' 
>       dfs(startingNode) 
>           {

```
        var visited = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < this.noOfVertices; i++) 
            visited[i] = false; 

        this.DFSUtil(startingNode, visited); 
    } 

    // Recursive function which process and explore 
    // all the adjacent vertex of the vertex with which it is called 
    DFSUtil(vert, visited) 
    { 
        visited[vert] = true; 
        console.log(vert); 

        var get_neighbours = this.AdjList.get(vert); 

        for (var i in get_neighbours) { 
            var get_elem = get_neighbours[i]; 
            if (!visited[get_elem]) 
                this.DFSUtil(get_elem, visited); 
        } 
    } '''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a tree first of the adjacent nodes and then travel the tree by looking for all possible nodes and return early with the first found sufficient result.

```js
function DSFTravel(matrix, size, start) {
    const
        traverse = (tree, node, visited = []) => {
            visited.push(node);
            if (visited.length === size) return visited;
            for (let n of tree[node]) {
                if (visited.includes(n)) continue;
                let result = traverse(tree, n, [...visited]);
                if (result.length === size) return result;
            }
            return [];
        },
        tree = matrix.reduce((r, a, i) => {
            r[i] = [];
            a.forEach((v, j) => v && r[i].push(j));
            return r;
        }, {});

    return traverse(tree, start);
}

var data = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]],
    result = DSFTravel(data, 4, 3);

console.log(result);
```